# cannot append Model.objects.all()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I cannot run `['abc'].append( MyModel.objects.all() )` since it generates exception `'NoneType' object is not iterable` if MyModel has no entry.

any workaround or something like `? :` in c++

**edit:**
my statement is actually

```
','.join([ str(e) for e in ['abc','def'].append( MyModel.objects.all() ) ])
```

it seems that the problem is caused by append() returning `NoneType`. I solved this by creating a variable to hold the list and then `extend()` it

Comment: What exception are you getting? Model.objects.all() should return empty list if there are no objects in the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be best to be explicit rather than implicit (and avoid using the short circuit propoerties of `or` which can lead to errors:

```
my_objects = MyModel.objects.all()
if my_objects:
    [a,b,c].extend(my_objects)
```

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
['abc'].append( MyModel.objects.all() or [])
```

Comment: OP's problem is caused by the in-place appending of a list. So you can't do it in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

`Model.objects.all()` [is a QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all) and that is iterable (see [the source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.1.1/django/db/models/query.py#L86)). Passing an iterator to `list.extend` works just fine: The contents of the iterator is unrolled nicely onto the end of the list.

NB: passing it to `list.append` puts the iterator object itself into the list, so most likely you want to `extend()`.

Answer (score 1):

None is returned from the append method, which takes place in place. In other words, your statement is equivalent to

```
[str(e) for e in None]
```

which naturally raises a NoneType exception. The solution is have a separate statement for the append or extend method, then follow blokeley's advice to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be += instead of append?

Comment: Why should it? `list.append(x)` is a valid method http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html